# Angular UI Router- insert param in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Working on a project where I am required to show url link and render data based on the param/id I pass in my url. In the following link AWS is the id.

**link:** http://link.com/Inventory/ListInventory/TID/AWS/JSON

**link:** http://link.com/Inventory/ListInventory/TID/param/JSON

[image]

Currently the data renders based on the id I select from the drop down but the url doesn't change. I have some code below but not sure what exactly I am doing wrong.

**App:**

```
define app
routes
$stateProvider
        .state('table', 
            {
                url: '/table',
                templateUrl: './js/views/tableTmpl.html',
                controller: 'tableCtrl'
            })
            .state('table.test', 
                {
                    url: '/test/:tid',
                    templateUrl: './js/views/tableTmpl.html',
                    controller: 'tableCtrl'
            });
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('inventory_app');

app.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope, tableService, uiGridConstants, $stateParams, $state) {

    /************************************************
    GLOBAL TEAM ID VALUES
    ************************************************/
    $scope.tids = ['AWS', 'RET', 'DO', 'HELLO', 'HG', 'MIM', 'ALL'];
    var globalteamId = 'AWS';

    $scope.tidsIdFunc = function(tidId) {
        globalteamId = tidId;

        $scope.itemClick = function(tid){
          $state.location('table.test', {'ID': tid})
        }; 

        /*Pass in argumnet for the functions below*/
        getCost(globalteamId);
        getAllData(globalteamId);
        pieGraph(globalteamId);
        histoGraph(globalteamId);
        lineGraph(globalteamId);
    };
```

**View**

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        TID ID
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li ng-repeat ="tid in tids">
          <!-- <a ng-click="tidsIdFunc(tid)">{{tid}}</a> -->
          <a ng-click="itemClick(tid)">{{tid}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Service**
Making HTTP call to json

Comment: I think that this `$state.location('table.test', {'ID': tid})` should look like this `$state.go('table.test', {tid: tid});` at least that's what i'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate to other state on item click, so better have it simple by using `ui-sref` directive in a place

```
<a ui-sref="table.test({tid: tid})">{{tid}}</a>
```

---

Real problem was you are calling wrong method of `$state` API to navigate through page.

It should be

```
$state.go('table.test', {'tid': tid})
```

instead of

```
$state.location('table.test', {'ID': tid})
```

Comment: Thank you this works! But when I copy and paste the URL on a new page, the data doesn't load. How can I fix that?